# Nginx and Haproxy listening on same port for different hosts

Tags: nginx, port, haproxy

Is it possible to have 2 different applications (nginx & haproxy) listen on the same port for different host names?

i.e:

haproxy:

```
frontend incoming_http
  bind www.freinds.com:80
```

nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name    www.spelling.com;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no.

However, you could possibly use one as a reverse proxy to send requests to the other (on, say, port 8080). I have used `nginx` to terminate SSL on port 443, and then routed the entire request through `haproxy`, so it might depend on the reasons you want to do what you're asking.